# Angular google maps: put image in Info window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps api angular (https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/windows) to display a map with a mark on it. The marked point, has its label with a few paragraphs and a picture.

The content of paragraphs displayed correctly, but not the image. The url of it is correct. Can add an image?

Some code:
HTML

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='datos.mapa.center' options="datos.mapa.opciones" zoom='datos.mapa.zoom'>
        <ui-gmap-marker coords="datos.marker_club.coords" 
                        options="datos.marker_club.options" 
                        idkey="datos.marker_club.id"
                        click="markerClick" >
            <ui-gmap-window show="datos.marker_club.show"  
                closeClick="markerClose(marker)" >
                <div><img class="mapa_escudo" scr="{{datos.escudo}}" width="32" height="32" />{{datos.club}}<br />Sede {{datos.sede}}</div>
            </ui-gmap-windows>
        </ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

JS

```
    $scope.datos.club               = 'Club';
    $scope.datos.sede               = 'Sede';
    $scope.datos.escudo             = 'http://www.server.com/image.png';
```

> ```
>       uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) {
>               $scope.datos.mapa           = { center: { latitude: latitud, longitude: longitud }, zoom: zoom };
>               $scope.datos.mapa.opciones  = { scrollwheel: true };        
>
>               var icon = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png";
>           $scope.datos.marker_club = {    id: 1,
>                                           coords: { latitude: latitud, longitude: longitud},
>                                           options:{ 
>                                                   draggable: false, 
>                                                   icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon),
>                                           },
>               };      $scope.markerClick = function(marker, eventName, model) {
>     $scope.datos.marker_club.show = !$scope.datos.marker_club.show;
> };
>
> $scope.markerClose = function(marker) {
>    $scope.datos.marker.show = false;
> };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just missing "ng-src" in the definition of the image!