# Api google maps - Directions service response

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

Using google maps api get route between two points. Response directions service is assigned to a Renderer Directions and displayed in html:

```
$scope.directionsDisplay = new maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService   = new maps.DirectionsService();
$scope.directionsDisplay.setMap( map.control.getGMap());
$scope.directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));

var request = {
        origin: ori.coords.latitude + ", " + ori.coords.longitude,
        destination: map.center.latitude + ", " + map.center.longitude,
        travelMode: maps.TravelMode['DRIVING'],
        unitSystem: maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        optimizeWaypoints: true
    };
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            $scope.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
```

This response shows the starting point, indications of the route and then the end point. Can not display the initial and end points? only indications. Or it can only be achieved by manipulating the response object? some similar example?

Thanks

Comment: In [your question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36346662/angular-google-maps-put-image-in-info-window), you were using Angular-google-maps. Today you are doing raw accesses to the API. Whats going on? Why did you switch?

Comment: Using both. With Angle-google-maps drawing the map and the initial and final points of the route. With DirectionsService the route. What I need it is that when you print it in the html not show the start and end points or failing to assign different CSS classes, so I need to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

With these instructions I remove the start and end points on the list of instructions as needed:

```
        delete response.routes[0].legs[0].start_address;
        delete response.routes[0].legs[0].end_address;
```